# "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Communications link failure" when GAE app tries to connect to multiple Google Cloud SQL databases

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have an application that connects to multiple databases within a single Google Cloud SQL instance. Based on a drop down selection, the GAE application will select records from one of 5 databases.

The problem is that when I select the first 4 databases (in no particular order in the drop down list), the GAE app connects successfully to the database and is able to retrieve records. But when I choose the fifth database from the drop down list, an error is thrown. The error and stack trace is as below. It is not an error with a specific database, as the error does not depend on the order of which database was selected. The last or fifth database chosen, immaterial of which, always fails with the same error message.

Any advise will be very much appreciated.

InspectAPI.java:

```
public Element[] getComponentsList(@Named("province")String provinceName, User user) throws Exception {

    if (user == null) {
        throw new UnauthorizedException("API calls must be authenticated.");
    }

    if (!AuthorizationService.hasAnyOrRoles(user.getEmail(), AuthorizationService.ROLE_ALL_ROLES)
                || !AuthorizationService.hasProvincieAccess(user.getEmail(), provinceName)) {
                throw new UnauthorizedException("You are not authorized to invoke this API method.");
            }

    EntityManager em = null;
    Element[] e = null;
    try {
        em = EMF.getFStore().createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        e = (ElementRubrieken[]) em.createQuery("SELECT i FROM Element i").getResultList()
                .toArray(new Element[0]);

    } catch (NoResultException nre) {
        // no result
        if (e == null) {
            return e;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Unable to get inspections.", ex);
        throw new InternalServerErrorException("Unable to get inspections.");
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            em.close();
        }
    }

    return e;
}
```

EMF.java

```
public static EntityManagerFactory getFicheStore() {
    if (emfFicheInstance == null) {
        Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
        if (SystemProperty.environment.value() == SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", System.getProperty("cloudsql.prod.f.url"));
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", System.getProperty("cloudsql.prod.f.user"));
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", System.getProperty("cloudsql.prod.f.password"));
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.db", System.getProperty("cloudsql.prod.f.db"));              
        } else {
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", System.getProperty("cloudsql.dev.f.url"));
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", System.getProperty("cloudsql.dev.f.user"));
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", System.getProperty("cloudsql.dev.f.password"));
            properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.db", System.getProperty("cloudsql.dev.f.db"));

        }

        emfFicheInstance = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
            System.getProperty("com.myproject.services.emfFactory.persistenceUnitName"), 
            properties);
    }

    return emfFicheInstance;
}
```

Error and stack trace:

```
E 00:42:39.184 com.myproject.api.InspectAPI getComponentsList: Unable to get inspections.
  javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Communications link failure

  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.NucleusJPAHelper.getJPAExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJPAHelper.java:270)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAQuery.getResultList(JPAQuery.java:202)
    at com.myproject.api.InspectAPI.getComponentsList(InspectAPI.java:223)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_$1.run(Method_.java:179)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.privilegedInvoke(Method_.java:176)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.invoke_(Method_.java:137)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.intercept.java.lang.reflect.Method_.invoke(Method_.java:45)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:359)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:160)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:118)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:254)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:484)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:438)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:445)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:309)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:301)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:442)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
  Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:46)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:350)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2416)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2450)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2235)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:818)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:46)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleNonRegisteringDriver$JdbcWrapper.getInstance(GoogleNonRegisteringDriver.java:276)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleNonRegisteringDriver.connect(GoogleNonRegisteringDriver.java:246)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.datasource.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverManagerConnectionFactory.java:78)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.datasource.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.datasource.dbcp.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1158)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.datasource.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:108)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionProviderPriorityList.getConnection(ConnectionProviderPriorityList.java:57)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.getConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:354)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.getXAResource(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:314)
    at org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl.enlistResource(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:354)
    at org.datanucleus.store.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl.allocateConnection(ConnectionManagerImpl.java:226)
    at org.datanucleus.store.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.getConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:60)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.getConnection(AbstractStoreManager.java:432)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.getConnection(AbstractStoreManager.java:401)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.JPQLQuery.performExecute(JPQLQuery.java:512)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:1789)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeWithMap(Query.java:1693)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAQuery.getResultList(JPAQuery.java:185)
  <continued in next message>
E 00:42:39.184 <continued from previous message>
    at com.myproject.api.InspectAPI.getComponentsList(InspectAPI.java:223)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:359)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:160)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:118)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:438)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:445)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:220)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:309)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:301)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:442)
    ... 1 more
  Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unable to open connection to the instance: myproject-tst:mysql
    at com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleCloudSqlSocket.<init>(GoogleCloudSqlSocket.java:48)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleCloudSqlSocketFactory.connect(GoogleCloudSqlSocketFactory.java:81)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
    ... 64 more
  Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /cloudsql/myproject-tst:mysql (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:247)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:132)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleCloudSqlSocket$RandomAccessFileHelper.getFile(GoogleCloudSqlSocket.java:249)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleCloudSqlSocket.<init>(GoogleCloudSqlSocket.java:46)
    ... 66 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two posibble reason for this error:

1. You are hitting the limit of 12 concurrent connections described here [1]. For some reason you might be not closing connections properly.
2. I'm not an expert on JPA but i think You need to stablish a single persistence unit per database yo want to connect to [2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/#Java_Managing_connections

[2] http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/hibernate-jpa/jpa-configuration/how-to-use-multiple-database-in-persistencexml

Comment: Hi Lionel, Yes I suspect that the 12 connection limit is also the source of the problem. Tried creating different persistence unit per database but it doesn't work. Also tried setting connection pool limits and it didn't work either. Am running out of ideas

Comment: @EthanS did you ever find a fix for the connection issue? I'm running into the same problem and haven't been able to get to a root cause. Its looking to us like retries might be the only option, but I'm hoping to avoid that.

Comment: @dansomething How frequently do you get the `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Communications link failure` errors? Are you using connection pooling? What's the average active connections to your Cloud SQL instance?

Comment: Hi @dansomething ... Can't recall from the top of my head. I'm asking my team mates if they remember how we overcame this (if we did). But I recalled a period of time where we played around with various JPA providers EclipseLink, etc ... Keep you posted if my colleagues have further information